# Solr cloud result grouping

Tags: solr, faceted-search, solrcloud

I have a solr schema which contains few index fields

Now i have different types of products which are distinguished by 'type' field. I want max 50 search results per search request.But the results should contain at least 5 products of each type, if they are part of the search.Say if i search for computer hardware store products, my search result should contain 5 HDDs,5 RAMs,5 CPUs,5 Mother boards etc. if these products are result of search.

In case if total returned rows for certain product type are less then 5, include what ever rows are available.

I have tried facet query and clustering, but could not succeeded.

Any ideas ? How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Solr field Collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) which will allows you to group results by product type.
Also, you can control the number of groups to be returned and number of entries in per group.